# Edit a child in buildForm

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, symfony-3.4

I am using Symfony 3.4.7. I work in Form. 
I have a formType with a function buildForm with some child. 
I add an eventListener to a few child. 
In the function which is attached to the eventListener, I would like to edit an existent child. But I want to edit a child which have also an eventListener attached.

This is the form that I have :

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;
// use ...

class ArticlesCategoriesType extends AbstractType
{
private $em;
private $ac;
private $max_long_arbo;

public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em, ArborescenceCategories $ac, $max_prof_arbo_cat)
{
    $this->em = $em;
    $this->ac = $ac;
    $this->max_long_arbo = $max_prof_arbo_cat;
}

/**
 * Construction du formulaire
 *
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $parents = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Categories')->findByParent(null);
    $builder

        ->add('categorie_enfant1', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Categories',
            'placeholder' => 'Sélectionnez la gamme',
            'choices' => $parents,
            'mapped' => false,
            'label' => ' '
        ])
        ->add('codeCategorie', HiddenType::class, [
            'label' => ' '
        ]);


        $builder->add('categorie_enfant2', HiddenType::class, [
            'mapped' => false,
            'label' => ' '
        ]);

    $builder->get('categorie_enfant1')->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
        function (FormEvent $event){
            $form = $event->getForm();
            /* @var $categorie Categories */
            $categorie = $form->getData();

            $this->addEnfantCategorie($event->getForm(), 2, $categorie);
        }
    );

    $builder->get('categorie_enfant2')->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
        function (FormEvent $event){
            $form = $event->getForm();
             /* @var $categorie Categories */
             $categorie = $form->getData();
             $this->addEnfantCategorie($form, 3, $categorie);
        }
    );
 }
 }
```

And the code of the function addEnfantCategorie:

```
<?php
public function addEnfantCategorie(FormInterface $form, $i, Categories $categorie){
    $builder = $form->getParent();
    // récupère les catégories enfants
    $categories = null;
    dump($form->getName().' '.$categorie);
    $categories = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Categories')->findByParent($categorie->getIdCategorie());
    $builder->add('categorie_enfant2', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Categories',
            'label'=> ' ',
            'placeholder' => 'Sélectionner la catégorie',
            'choices' => $categories,
            'mapped' => false
        ]);
}
```

To edit a child I find the solution to add the child with the same name as the one who I have added in the origin builder. But it erases the eventListener which is attached to it.

I don't find a solution to just edit a child and not erase the child with the same name.
I hope there is an existing solution to do that.

[EDIT 1]
In the result I want an undetermined number of button. The maximum number of button is determine by a global variable. 
[image]
The button 1 display just the categories who don't have parents. When I select a category on the button 2 I want that it displays the categories who are the child of category 1 and etc for the rest of the button. This is why I need in the form an eventListener for all button. To display this dynamically I use Javascript.

[EDIT 2]
I tried to you use embed form. 
This is the code for the form which is embed :

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use ...

class CategoryType extends AbstractType{

private $em;

public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
{
    $this->em = $em;
}

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $parents = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Categories')->findByParent(null);
    $builder->add('reference', EntityType::class, [
        'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Categories',
        'placeholder' => 'Sélectionner la gamme',
        'choices' => $parents,
        'label' => ' '
    ]);
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => Categories::class,
    ));
}
}
```

I would to pass an attribute in the form CatgeoryType which is a parent. I would like to use this attribute 'parent' to get all the child of this parent. But I don't know how I can do that.

And in my main form ArticlesCatgeories, when I  add in my builder a CatgeoryType I would like send the parameters 'parent' which is the category who is selected by the precedent 'categorie_enfant'.

This is the code for my main form ArticlesCategoriesType:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use ...

class ArticlesCategoriesType extends AbstractType
{
private $em;
private $ac;
private $max_long_arbo;

public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em, ArborescenceCategories $ac, $max_prof_arbo_cat)
{
    $this->em = $em;
    $this->ac = $ac;
    $this->max_long_arbo = $max_prof_arbo_cat;

}

/**
 * Construction du formulaire
 *
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $enfants = $this->ac->getDernierEnfants($this->em);
    $builder
        ->add('codeCategorie', null, [
            'placeholder' => 'Sélectionnez une catégorie',
            'choices' => $enfants
        ])
        // ... others attributes 
    ->add('categorie_enfant1', CategoryType::class, [
        'parent' => 'A1'
    ])
    ->add('categorie_enfant2', CategoryType::class, [
            'mapped' => false,
            'label' => ' '
        ]);
     }
   }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Did you tried to use embed form? Seems a better approach for your case. (if I understood correctly) https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/embedded.html

Comment: Thank you to your answer. I tried to use embed form but I can't do what I want with this solution. I explain in detail what I want in my question.

Comment: Well. Too hard to me to know all about your needed, but I guess that if each `categories input` was a embeded form, you can control each one individually and add how many entries you need with a simple `loop for` => `$parent_form->add('another_categorie', CategoryFormType::class, array('some_attribute_to_inform_you_needed_on_configure' => $val))`. I did something similar and works fine. Can you publish your scripts somewhere?

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. As you understood, I need an attribute for my form (the form which is embed) `parent` to find all categories which are a child of the `parent`. 

I did'nt succeed to reproduced your example. I don't understand how I can pass an attribute with this `array('some_attribute_to_inform_you_needed_on_configure' => $val))`. 
I edit my question to post my code. You can see on [EDIT 2].